# Jenkins conditional steps for maven project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I use Jenkins for continuous integration.

How can I run conditional steps with Maven projects ? For free style projects I am able to set up conditional steps but this seems not available with Maven projects.

Additionally I also want to publish findbugs/pmd reports conditionally in maven projects. Again this looks possible using flexible publish plugin only for free style projects.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

-Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add a profile in your POM and activate it only when a variable (Only setted by Jenkins for example) is present. A bit like this:

```
<profiles>
   <!-- Jenkins by default defines a property BUILD_NUMBER which is used to 
        enable the profile. -->
   <profile>
      <id>coverage</id>
      <activation>
         <property>
            <name>env.BUILD_NUMBER</name>
         </property>
      </activation> 
      <build>
      </build>
   </profile>
</profiles>
```

Alternatively, you can add some profiles add using them manually in the Jenkins command line:

```
mvn -P coverage
```

Comment: Basically my requirement is that I have 2 jenkins builds running different maven goals

1. Continuous build running every hour
2. Nightly build running once in a day

I want to merge them into single build so that the goals of nightly build can be run only when some condition is met, otherwise run the goals of continuous build.

Similarly I want to publish pmd/findbugs results only for nightly build.
I am able to do similar thing in free style projects in jenkins but not with maven project.

Comment: Ok. I would probably play with different profiles based on different env variables setted by Jenkins